# Add event to calender in React Native/Expo

Tags: react-native, calendar, create-react-native-app, expo-go

I wish to build an event-calender with expo which is similar to how sync fusion scheduler for React works.  What I know of sync fusion doesn't exist for React Native.

Any advice on which library to use and how to go about to make a calender with React Native, preferably with expo,

where it is possible to add events with both start time and end time and view it as a calender.

Grateful for any advice